# Loop through rows that do and do not have data

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Sheet(1) that will look for rows on a different sheet(2) that contain data. if the rows in Sheet(2) have data, then their information will populate in Sheet(1). I need a loop to go through and take action on the lines in Sheet(1), and be able to skip over a number of blank rows to get to the next set of information.

I have a loop that will go through to the last row of data, but it goes through all lines with information until there is a blank row. I need something that will go through blank rows to continue looking for rows with data.

```
function sendEmails() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells A2:B2
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, 6);
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var dataRangee = sheet.getRange("D2");
var qdate = dataRangee.getDisplayValues(); 
var dataRangeee = sheet.getRange("E2");
var ddate = dataRangeee.getDisplayValues();
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[2]; // Third column
var subject = 'Request';
var body = "Dear general partner,"
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxx');
var copy = row[5]; // Sixth column
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body, {cc: copy, attachments: 
[file]});
} 
}
```

This code is the one mentioned above that loops thru until it reaches a blank row.

Comment: In an effort to save time here.  How about posting public link to your spreadsheet (removed private information) and please post the code that you have now.  The code has to meet the requirements of [mcve].

Comment: Edited to show the entire code being used, again this one loops until it finds a blank space. I'd like it to go thru the sheet and look for any rows that have information. There will never be more than 500 rows, I'm thinking I could just have it look for data within the first 500 rows?

Comment: It fails on the sendMail() because the emailAddress and/or the copy maybe undefined and you have not implemented a way to recover from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,6).getValues();
  //var qdate=sh.getRange("D2").getDisplayValue(); //not used
  //var ddate=sh.getRange("E2").getDisplayValue(); //not used
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxx');
  var subject = 'Request';
  var body = "Dear general partner," 
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(data[i][2] && data[i][5]) {//if email or copy are undefined just skip
      var emailAddress = data[i][2]; // Third column
      var copy = data[i][5]; // Sixth column
      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body, {cc: copy, attachments:[file]});
    }
  } 
}
```

You should reserve the use of this sort of loop for key/value objects `for (i in data) {` and you should always declare `i with var i=`

Comment: Cooper this is great, thank you so much for taking the time!